# Reason for infinite loop

Tags: c, sequence-points

```
signed char ch=5;
while(ch = ch--)
    printf("%d",ch);
```

I read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point). It is clearly stated that while statement and end of a statement(;) are sequence points.

So i don't understand why the above one runs infinite time and prints same value[5].

Comment: I am ssigning the value. Not checking for equalit

Comment: change `(ch = ch--)` to `(ch --)`

Comment: For that link alone, i have posted the details o sequence points

Comment: `ch = ch--` Is undefined behaviour. In your case, I imagine that `ch--` is evaluated (`ch`'s value is saved, *then* `ch` is decremented) and *then* `ch` is assigned to the saved value (the old one), thus not changing `ch` in the end.

Comment: @Dettorer, yeah i need this explanation. please explain with numbers rather than words. I am confusing little bit.

Comment: Hum... Are you just why it is an infinite loop (answer: undefined behaviour of `ch = ch--`) or are you trying to do something? If so, please detail what you want to do and we'll be happy to help :).

Comment: @Dettorer, Yeah i want to know why it is infinite loop alone

Comment: [Have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) maybe (first answer defines what is an undefined behaviour). The problem is that your code's behaviour (or "result") is not specified by the C standard, so it can do things completely different (and likely unwanted) with another computer, another OS, another compiler, another surrounding code etc. It simply isn't defined. On your computer with your compiler and this particular piece of code, it does an infinite loop.

Comment: There is a sequence point at the semicolon of ch=5;. There is a sequence point at the _end_ of the while statement while(...). Between those two sequence points, ch is written to twice, therefore this is UB. See the duplicate link for details.

Answer (score 5):

Your code should be

```
signed char ch=5;
while(ch--)
    printf("%d",ch);
```

as `ch--` already is an assignment. You reassigned `ch` to its previous value before `ch--` with `ch = ch--` so `ch--` has no effect and you get the same value at each iteration.

Comment: Hi, my doubt is that, while(ch=0){} ll fail. right?

Comment: @Rizier123, while(0) isn't false in C?

Comment: wrong, while(0) will be evaluated to false.

Comment: @specializt Smilarly, at 5th iteration ch ll be 0. isn't? i dont understand the point here.How old value gets preserved?

Comment: i ... cant decipher your words, sorry. I recommend polishing your english-skills as software development heavily depends on this language.

Comment: The code given here is correct and the loop is executed 5 times (it prints "43210"). `ch` is decremented each time the `while`'s condition is evaluated.

Comment: @specializt OK fine. According to my assumption, ch gets decremented for each iteration in my CODE. At 5th iteration, ch will be 0. while(ch=0) is false. So it should come out of while loop. But Dettorer said ch-- has no effect in while loop condition[i.e ch=ch--] . I don't understand this.

Comment: With `while(ch--)`, `ch` gets decremented at each iteration. With `while(ch=ch--)` you can't tell what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    signed char ch=5;

    while(ch--)
        printf("%d\n",ch);



    return 0;

}
```